# How to trigger instructions on an element created dynamically with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use Ajax to create dynamically something like 100 div with a function called lambda() and then I want to scroll on one of the new div (id='new_id') with Jquery but failed because when my

```
//lambda()//<--create $('#new_id') dynamically
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#new_id').offset().top
}, 500);
```

is fired, the DOM is not updated in time and the $('#new_id') returns undefined.
So, I need something like .ready for this specific selector to tell me when the DOM is ready to be used.
I know that .on must be used when you want to attach an event to a dynamic content but my problem is only for instructions immediately triggered with no event, just an immediate scrolling.

Thank you for your help.

### EDIT: detailed & purified code:

1/the chk() function is triggered with a submit event
2/inside chk(), $.ajax will add some data in DB, let's say it's a div content
3/if success, if the php doesn't return an error (data.err), it triggers my callback function lambda()
4/lambda() will display the new div content + the old ones (=data.com) on $('#bloc_com'), it's an update function
5/when lambda() has finished, I want the animation to work to scroll up to $('#'+data.new_id)

.ajaxComplete WORKS but $.when() + .done()/.then() NO!
However, I have others ajax functions on this page and .ajaxComplete is triggered for all of them and it's not what I want.

```
function lambda(p){
    var b=$('#bloc_com');
    var com_in=$('#com_in');

    $.get('ajax/com_pagination.php',{p:p},function(data)
        {
            b.html(data.com);//update the webpage
        },'json'
    ).fail(function() {
        com_in.html("<span class='erreur222'>Error system. If the problem persists, please contact the administration.</span>");
    });
    return false;
}

function chk(){
    var err=$('#err_com');

    $.when($.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'ajax/com_chk.php',
        data:{id:id,dt:time,cm:com},
        success:function(data)
        {
            err.html(data.err);//display error
            if(data.err=='')
            {
                var p=1;
                lambda(p);//callback function that will display the 100 div with the new one which this ajax call adds in DB

                //.ajaxComplete works here!
                /*$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $('#'+data.new_id).offset().top
                    }, 500);
                });*/
            }
        },
        dataType:'json'
    })).then(function() {
        alert('done method fired!');//it's working
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#'+data.new_id).offset().top//return undefined
        }, 500);
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Just call this event after your content is loaded? And, please post the function that does the loading

Comment: after creating the element you should place it in the DOM then you can select it and do whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track but you have to think of who knows what to be able to scroll at the good moment.

The function which knows when the html elements added on your page by AJAX is not the chk() function, so it does not make sense to put your scroll there, even though the end of the chk() function should be after the end of the lamba() function.

The easiest way to solve your problem would be then to put the "complete" function offered by jQuery in your lambda() function, but you are using the $.get function there and it does not offer the complete option. This can be easily solved by using the more flexible function $.ajax just like you did with chk(), but instead of using type:"POST" you would use type:"GET".

With this, you can use the complete function offered by ajax to know exactly when your elements are ready in the DOM, it would look like this

```
$.ajax(
type:"GET",
url:'ajax/com_pagination.php'
data:{p:p}
success:function(data)
    {
        b.html(data.com);//update the webpage
    },
'json'
error:function() {
    com_in.html("<span class='erreur222'>Error system. If the problem persists, please contact the administration.</span>");
},
complete:function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#'+data.new_id).offset().top
    }, 500);
);
```

I also hacked up a little jsfiddle there if you want to have a look http://jsfiddle.net/HcvL3/

Comment: Thank you! In fact, I tried to apply the precedent answers with .done(), .when()+.then() with a .get() method and all work fine when I applied them to the right function. So, multiple good answers but you touch the right spot.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your function into a construct that will be fired just when your ajax call is done.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  //your function
});
```

[ajaxComplete Reference](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

Otherwise you can use .when() construct to obtain the same result in a different way

Example: Execute the function myFunc when both ajax requests are successful, or myFailure if either one has an error.

Example:

#### Execute a function after two ajax requests are successful. (See the jQuery.ajax() documentation for a complete description of success and error cases for an ajax request).

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) )
  .then( myFunc, myFailure );
```

[when Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Comment: ajaxComplete works perfectly fine but I have others ajax functions on this page and .ajaxSuccess is triggered for all of them. Your when+then solution doesn't work. See my first post, I updated it with a lot of detail.

Comment: After KirKill told me that I used the wrong function, your answer with .when() and .then() works but no need of the when method, "then" is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajaxSuccess ( http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/ ) to see when the ajax call has finished.

Something like this:

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function() {
//lambda()//<--create $('#new_id') dynamically
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#new_id').offset().top
}, 500);
});
```

Comment: ajaxSuccess or ajaxComplete works perfectly fine but I have others ajax functions on this page and .ajaxSuccess is triggered for all of them. See my first post, I updated it with a lot of detail.

Answer (score 0):

You must animate when ajax is completely done so try this:

```
    function testAjax(handleData) {
  $.ajax({
    url:"yourURL",  
    success:function(data) {
       $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#new_id').offset().top
}, 500);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access new element only after it actually gets created.
Use ajax.done

```
$.ajax({
  ....
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#new_id').offset().top
    }, 500);
  });
```

Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery triggers the ajaxComplete() event. So its better use this way, instead of using ajaxComplete(). This will be executed only for this ajax call.

Comment: You are right about the ajaxComplete() event but it works when the .done() method doesn't. See my first post, I updated it with a lot of detail.

Comment: After KirKill told me that I used the wrong function, your answer with .done() works.